# How do I add a class to a div based on it's content using JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to find the class "attachment", and if it's content contains the string ".csv", then add a class "icon-file-excel"

HTML

```
<div id="attachments">
    <a class="attachment" href="#">ContentLink__c.csv — application/vnd.ms-excel 11517 bytes —</a>
    <a class="attachment" href="#">LTC.txt — text/plain 18349 bytes —</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var att = document.getElementsByClassName('.attachment');
if (att.innerHTML.indexOf(".csv") != -1) {
    att.className = attachment.className + " icon-file-excel";
}
```

Comment: are you supposed to use jQuery?

Comment: No, I need to use Javascript to do this.

Comment: `att` is going to be an array of matching nodes. it's not something you can then just do a .innerhtml call on. you'd have to loop on the result and check each individual matching node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop the result. `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTML collection`. That's an arrayish object containing 1 or multiple elements.

A few other edits:

- `document.getElementsByClassName('attachment');` Don't use a dot here. Just the classname
- select the elements with `[index]`
- `att[i].className += " icon-file-excel";` Just use `+=` to append a string to the class name.

```js
var att = document.getElementsByClassName('attachment');

for (var i = 0; i < att.length; i++)
{
   if (att[i].innerHTML.indexOf(".csv") != -1) {
     
       att[i].className += " icon-file-excel";
   }
}
```

```css
.icon-file-excel {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="attachments">
    <a class="attachment" href="#">ContentLink__c.csv — application/vnd.ms-excel 11517 bytes —</a>
    <a class="attachment" href="#">LTC.txt — text/plain 18349 bytes —</a>
</div>
```

A few improvement tips:

- instead of `document.getElementsByClassName`, you could use `document.querySelectorAll` which allows you to select with *css selectors* like `.attachments` and also returns an HTML collection.
- Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)  to add and remove classes from an element. More robust than appending strings.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-ish list of matching elements. You can't treat it like an element. Since it's array-like, you have to loop on that array and do the string test on each of the array's elements.

```
var atts = document.getElementsByClassName('.attachment');
for (i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
   if (atts[i].innerHTML etc...) { 
       atts[i].className = ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This will fail right now because of the dot in `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

- You need to iterate throught the selected elements. There could be many of them.
- You're using inconsistent variable names.
- You should not have a dot in the string provided to `getElementsByClassName()`.

```js
var attachments = document.getElementsByClassName('attachment');
for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i += 1) {
    att = attachments[i];
    if (att.innerHTML.indexOf(".csv") !== -1) {
        att.className = att.className + " icon-file-excel";
    }
}
```

In newer browsers, you can use `.classList`, which is more robust:

```
if (att.innerHTML.indexOf(".csv") !== -1) {
    att.classList.add("icon-file-excel");
}
```

Comment: As a point of Javascript best practices, you'll want to store the result of `attachments.length` in a variable, rather than use it directly in the `for` loop.  Javascript is funny that way.

Comment: @BrianJ True, but I would say that's outside the scope of this question, especially because the `attachments.length` cost applies specifically to collections of DOM elements.

Comment: @BrianJ,only when iterating over many many objects will that improve performance notably.

Comment: @JLRishe, this will fail, look at the dot in the `getElementsByClassName`